# Left it for when

Tags: word-usage, usage

I read this sentence online:

> I left it for when I'll be a more advanced speaker.

It was written by someone who was trying to read a novel, but couldn't understand it, stopped reading it until he levelled up. Is the use of "left" and "for when" natural here?

Comment: To leave something for a later time is a normal expression. My friend gave me a cigarette, but I left it for after my meal.

Comment: do you mean that "leave it for when" is correct?

Comment: Yes @lee that's what I meant to ask.

Comment: yes it is correct. you can find it in the book of "Displacing Human Rights: War and Intervention in Northern Uganda" on page 3, (I left it for when I knew people better). there exist other examples on other books. Indeed, It is : "leave it (for) when"

Comment: @lee The tenses in your example are different from the OP: yours uses the past "knew" OP has future "Ill be"

Comment: Using “left it for when” is perfectly correct, but there are two other issues here - “be” should be “become“ and the clash of tense: *I left it for when I became a more advanced speaker. OR I’ll leave it for when I become a more advanced speaker.* Have a look at the definition of “become”.